# jquery on drag, disregard overlayed (absolute) positioned element

Tags: jquery, events, drag, css-position

Please check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rzbut/7/)

This is the html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="button_area"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
<div>​
```

The icon is positioned atop of the button_area.

Now I have to drag the .button_area:
$('.button_area').draggable({});

it works if I click on the area and start dragging

but if I click on the .icon (that is on top of the area) and start dragging, nothing happens...

For firefox and chrome I've found a solution gere in stackoverflow, pretty simple one, just adding a simple css urle to the .icon and I am golden.

```
.icon{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The problem is this doesnt work on opera nor ie.

what would be the best solution to make it work crossbrowser (I don't mind ie6, 7 and 8)...

Comment: is the `icon` accepts events?

Comment: why not put the `icon` inside `button_area`?

Comment: 'couse it would be dragging with it